# How to determine roll pitch and yaw/Euler angles from approximately orthogonal matrix?

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation, geometric-transform

I have a collection of rigid bodies, each comprising ~100 particles. Each body is defined by a list of points corresponding to the coordinates of its constituent particles. The rigid bodies are approximately identical (i.e. there should exist a rigid body motion that maps each body onto any other body), though some statistical noise in the algorithm that determined the particle positions makes them not *exactly* identical. I want to determine the center of mass and orientation of each rigid body.

The simplest way to do this seems to be using the function FindGeometricTransform. Using this, I have determined a translation vector and a transformation matrix $R$ to transfer one body to another. I would like to use this matrix to determine the Euler/Tait-Bryan/roll-pitch-yaw angles between each body. However, the matrix obtained by FindGeometricTransform is not exactly a rotation matrix because of the aforementioned statistical noise. Hence, RollPitchYawAngles returns an error. How can I find an approximate set of angles to transform between the different bodies?

Comment: One alternative method I could use is to find the center of mass and principle axes of each body directly, which I could of course use to determine an exact rotation matrix. But I'd prefer something a bit more elegant, and something that scales a bit more nicely in the event that I have to do this for many more bodies in the future.

Comment: Maybe you could try QR decomposition and use Q as the rotation matrix. But I'm not sure if it's relevant in your case (i.e. I don't know such a Q is robust to noise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Orthogonalize` seems to do the job when the noise is not too large. Of course if the data is very noisy, then `FindGeometricTransform` will not return the result you are looking for.

Below, `pts0` is the original set of points, `pts1` is the transformed nosiy data, rotated by an angle $0.5$ (the unknown angle we are looking for).

```
SeedRandom[2018]
pts0 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 2}];
noiseFactor = 0.1;
pts1 = RotationMatrix[0.5].#& /@ (noiseFactor*RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}] + pts0);
t = FindGeometricTransform[pts0, pts1];
r = t[[2, 1, ;; 2, ;; 2]];
rot = Orthogonalize@r;
ArcCos[rot[[1, 1]]] (* mind the sign *)
(* 0.497794 *)
```

The result is very close to $0.5$.

[image]

With more noise (`noiseFactor = 0.5`) you get `0.489369` which is not too bad.

[image]

**Edit** The above approach seems to give the same result as specifying `TransformationClass -> "Rigid"` in `FindGeometricTransform`. Thus it is even simpler to use

```
t = FindGeometricTransform[pts0, pts1, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];
ArcCos[t[[2, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

Comment: Thanks much, this works perfectly. My alignment error for FindGeometricTransform was around 10^-4, so I'm well within the tolerance of this method.

Comment: @ZachMcDargh Good. Just be careful with the sign in `ArcCos`, I did not take into account `rot[[1, 2]]` for simplicity but you might want to improve that to ensure you have the right sign in the angle.

Comment: Be careful with Orthogonalize[]! The best guess for the unknown rotation vector(small rotation)  is `dr=(r-Transpose[r])/2` ,The angle is `dr[[2,1]]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Where does the expression for `dr` comes from? I found a cleaner approach, that _seems_ to be the same as with `Orthogonalize`, see edit.

Comment: @anderstood: Rotation can be expressed with `MatrixExponential Exp[phi]` with skew `symmetric phi=-phi^t`. In german it's called natural rotation(Euler). I develop the formulas in an answer

Comment: Instead of `ArcCos[]`, I would probably use two-argument arctangent on the first row of the rotation matrix. Thus: `{err, tf} = FindGeometricTransform[pts0, pts1, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"]; -ArcTan @@ TransformationMatrix[tf][[1, {1, 2}]]`

Answer (score 0):

The 2D-rotationmatrix can be expressed (one possibility)

```
\[Phi] = {{0, -\[CurlyPhi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0}} 
R=IdentityMatrix[2] + (Sin[\[CurlyPhi]] \[Phi])/\[CurlyPhi] + ((1 -Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]) \[Phi].\[Phi])/\[CurlyPhi]^2
(* euler angle \[CurlyPhi]*)
```

The difference

```
S=(R-Transpose[R])/2
(*{{0, -Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]}, {Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 0}} *)
```

gives a skew matrix S, containing the euler angle of the given rotation, which can be evaluated by solving the equation

```
 Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]== S[[2,1]] (* S=(r-r^t)/2*)
 (*{\[CurlyPhi] -> -0.510147}*)
```

Comment: But my rotations are not small at all, in fact they span the entire unit circle.

Comment: In my answer there is no assumption about small angles!